# 4096 float numbers and 2 options which is best way and why?

Tags: c

Ok I have 4096 float numbers and I have 2 options how to store them in to array:

Which option you would use and why?

1. Existing array inside program

   ```
     const float AB[4096] = {1.83839f, 2.99345f, .... };
   ```
2. Loop array at program startup

   ```
    float A[64] = {9.37373f, ....};
    float B[64] = {1.37373f, ....};
    float AB[4096] ={0};
    int i=0;

    for(a=0; a < 8; a++)
      for(b=0; b < 8; b++)
        for(x=0; x < 8; x++)
          for(z=0; z < 8; z++)
              AB[i++] = A[(b*8+x)] * B[z+(8*a)];
   ```

Comment: What do you mean by "existing array inside program"?

Comment: It seems that the question is really "Should I manually define an array with 4096 numbers or generate them at runtime with 128 numbers?" It's really up to whether you prefer readability and small source files or require runtime performance.

Comment: Personally I would have upvoted this question but the added P.S. was totally inappropriate.

Comment: @ouah inappropriate is vote down which making people walk away from this website. I'm human and I do mistakes.

Answer (score 2):

To avoid the runtime overhead of calculating what is essentially constant data, and the tedious and error prone entry of a large initialiser, a simple compromise is to write code that calculates the initialisers and itself generates code with a constant initialiser.  Then you build the generated code into your application.

Comment: So option 1 is the answer?

Comment: @Eveler : Not really; it is *an answer*, only practical with code generation (or copy & paste from a spreadsheet perhaps).  The generating code will look a lot like *option 2*.  So this answer is in fact a hybrid.